# Why Matlab shows "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."?

Tags: matlab

Here is my matlab code:

```
gg=imread('fsu_Westcott.jpg');
data1=gg(:,1);
histArray1=zeros(1,256);
x=0:1:255;
for n=1:length(data1)
histArray1(1,data1(n)+1)=histArray1(1,data1(n)+1)+1;
end
for n=1:length(data1)
number1=sum(histArray1(1:n));
end
plot(x,number1,'r')
```

Why it shows "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."? before I finally plot? I am new and thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like you have a couple things you'll want to fix. To fix the error on the line Simon pointed out, I think you'll want to have your 2nd `For` loop going from 1 to `length(histArray)` (or 256) instead of `length(data1)`. The second problem I see is that in the 2nd `For` loop you aren't building an array--you're just redefining the variable `number1` over and over. You should probably put `number1(n)=sum(histArray1(1:n));` inside that for loop instead. This doesn't have to do with the error you're seeing but it might help you get what you want out of the script.

Answer (score 3):

On the line:

```
number1=sum(histArray1(1:n));
```

you are asking for cells 1 to `n` of array `histArray1` but `n` goes from 1 to `length(data1)` which is larger than the length of `histArray1` (256). So it is out of bounds.

This loop:

```
for n=1:length(data1)
    number1=sum(histArray1(1:n));
end
```

seems unnecessary if you want to plot the histogram anyway.

One more tip, there is a function called [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) which you could use to both compute the histogram *and* plot the result in a barchart in one line:

```
hist(data1(:), 0:255)
```